# How do I enable Bluetooth for Androidx86 8.1rc2 VM in Virtual Box running on Ubuntu 18

Tags: android, bluetooth, virtualbox, android-x86

I'm trying to enable Bluetooth on my Android VM using the following

- Ubuntu 18.04.1
- Virtual Box 6.0.2 r128162 with Extension Pack 6.0.2 r128162
- Android-x86 8.1rc2
- Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

I've added my user to the **vboxusers** group as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox) which allowed me to see the Bluetooth dongle in the VMs list of USB devices. I added a filter and tried booting the device with and without the dongle connected and neither allowed me to toggle bluetooth on.

### Terminal Emulator on Android

Running 
`hcitool dev
Devices:`
 return no devices.

`hciconfig -a`
[image]

Running hciconfig hci0 up
[image]

Can't init device hci0: Operation not permitted(1)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may enable Bluetooth only if you have root access. Use `su` before running `hciconfig hci0 up`:

No root access:

[image]

Wit root access:

[image]

Comment: That's indeed the case. That crappy `dmesg` screenshot just confused me... however, it doesn't really answer the question of how one could expose it to Android x86 on VirtualBox.

Comment: You're right, I can run BT commands like `hcitools lescan` in shell but BT is not really exposed to other apps.

Comment: In recent versions of the Android emulator, there's even BT ...but it may be fake. And on Linux one often has to load firmware to get it working. I mean, even if the host OS can handle it (as the screenshot suggests), the Android OS still would require the firmware added. Just tried with a BT dongle and a hardware device ...it isn't operational, even if it detects it an USB device.